# React redux toolkit 'Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'check')

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

Im try to make a todo list with React and Redux Toolkit, i searching for this error so many times but still don't have a answer to solve a problem.

I think my action.payload is well defined. removeItem, toggleItem is worked fine, but i can only using one of them. When i add toggleItem function, i received the following error

```
Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'check')
```

Here are my full code on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-bqmjz1?file=redux%2Ffeatures%2FtodoSlice.ts

**createSlice.ts file**

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const todoSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'todo',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addItem: (state, action: PayloadAction<Todo>) => {
      const newItem = {
        id: new Date().getTime().toString(),
        title: action.payload.title,
        check: action.payload.check,
      };
      state.unshift(newItem);
    },
    removeItem: (state, action: PayloadAction<Todo>) => {
      return state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id);
    },

    //Toggle check 
    toggleCheck: (state, action: PayloadAction<Todo>) => {
      const index = state.findIndex((item) => item.id === action.payload.id);
      state[index].check = action.payload.check;
    },
  },
});

export const { addItem, removeItem, toggleCheck } = todoSlice.actions;

export default todoSlice.reducer;
```

**TodoItem.tsx **

```
const TodoItem = ({ item }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleRemove = () => {
    dispatch(removeItem({ id: item.id }));
  };

  const handleToggle = () => {
    dispatch(toggleCheck({ id: item.id, check: !item.check }));
  };

  return (
    <li
      className={`border border-2 list-group-item my-2 ${
        item.check ? 'border-primary text-primary' : 'border-dark'
      }`}
      onClick={handleToggle}
    >
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <h4>{item.title}</h4>
        <i onClick={handleRemove} className="fas fa-times text-danger"></i>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};

export default TodoItem;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the `cross` icon, the click event is also propagated to the parent element `li`. So, when you click on cross, first `handleRemove` will be called. And then, `handleToggle` will be called. But, by the time `handleToggle` is called, the item is already removed from the list and hence, you are not able to change the `check` property of the item as `const index = state.findIndex((item) => item.id === action.payload.id);` will be `-1` in the `toggleCheck` function and there is no item at index `-1`.

To fix this, you can do the following in `handleRemove` function:

```js
const handleRemove = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  dispatch(removeItem({ id: item.id }));
};
```

So, if you click on `cross` icon, it won't propagate the click event to the parent `li` event and `handleToggle` won't be invoked.